# How to prevent that Outlook starts session in Skype?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, skype, session, chat

When I access to my mail on the Outlook page, automatically it starts my session in Skype so in the Outlook page I can receive all the messages that the people send me via Skype, the problem is that I don't want that people can talk me from Skype if I'm just looking my new mails in the Outlook page...

I have som clients in the Skype and when I have the Outlook page opened I can't notice most of the messages that they send me from Skype 'cause I'm not inside skype I just have the Outlook page opened to read or write mails... I don't want that Outlook starts session in Skype and receive private messages from they in silly notify popups in the Outlook page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you taking about web based outlook , if yes then you must have linked the skype with your outlook , un link it. It is a skype plugin.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12247/how-do-i-call-video-call-and-instant-message-my-outlook-com-contacts

Regards

suyash

Comment: Thanks, yes I can suppose that ... but stills totally unclear to me how to unlink it. In that link shows how to add contancts from skype to Outlook or something but nothing about how to deactivate Skype user session in the web based Outlook. I can't see any related option in the Outlook chat pane or the outlook settings.

Comment: Well I've found a tutorial here: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Sign-out-of-Skype-at-Outlook-com/td-p/1712304

Comment: The skype installs this plugin into your system, just check in your add/remove program and uninstall it.

Comment: No, there is any plugin related to skype/outlook. was not a plugin, it happens with Skype closed..